# Problema al ejecutar reporte jasper en jsp

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports, ireport

**Estimados**

Tengo un problema al ejecutar en una pagina jsp ,un reporte creado en ireport jasperReport .El reporte se creó correctamente y se puede visualizar en la opción de vista previa de netbeans pero al ejecutarlo desde jsp ocurre una excepcion.

Acá imagen del reporte creado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá el botón de donde se ejecuta el reporte en la vista reportes.jsp

```
<a href="vistaReporteVuelos.jsp">Ver</a>
```

Acá el código de la vista donde se muestra el reporte

```
<%   


                            Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
                        File reportFile=new File(application.getRealPath("reportes/reporteVuelosMasUsados.jasper"));
                        Map parametros=new HashMap();
                        byte [] bytes= JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parametros,conn);
                        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

                        ServletOutputStream output=response.getOutputStream();
                        response.getOutputStream();
                        output.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                        output.flush();
                        output.close();

%>
```

Al ejecutarlo se cae la pagina con la siguiente exception

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código se la excepción

Exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\vigouroux\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Abril\27-04-2019\AirExpressAdmin\build\web\reportes\reporteVuelosMasUsados.jasper
```

Causa Raíz

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\vigouroux\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Abril\27-04-2019\AirExpressAdmin\build\web\reportes\reporteVuelosMasUsados.jasper
```

Causa Raíz

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\vigouroux\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Abril\27-04-2019\AirExpressAdmin\build\web\reportes\reporteVuelosMasUsados.jasper
```

Por favor su ayuda con este error ya que la ruta del archivo está
el archivo del reporte jasper esta dentro de un package llamado reportes y el link para llamar el reporte está reportes\reporteVuelosMasUsados.jasper

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya encontre el problema , era la ubicación de la carpeta. habia que agregarla en la capa web pero ahora ocurre otro problema . ahora muestra la siguiente excepction: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/jfree/chart/plot/PlotOrientation;

Comment: Hola ya resolví el problema, había que importar groovy